# Regular expression to identify separators between words

Tags: regex

I am trying to separate words in a text. I need to split them by anything between them so I wrote a regular expression that works ***almost*** as it should.

Words are alphabetic strings that can contain dashes (-), they cannot start with dashes or end with dashes. Words cannot contain numerals or any other character besides single dashes and [a-zA-Z].

This is what I came up with so far:

```
/(-[^a-zA-Z])|\w*\d\w*|[^a-zA-Z-]+/ig
```

This, however, does not work correctly for words starting with a dash, such as this situation:

```
123-word
```

That should match

```
123-
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

**Update**

Sorry, I was rather vague. I need to match what is between words, not the words themselves, so I can do a split into an array further on.

This is what matches so far with the expression above:
[image]

... and this is how it should be like:
[image]

Notice the difference of matching at the second text line (123-)
Sorry for not being specific enough.

Comment: This is confusing, are you "identifying separators" or "separating words" or matching something? Can you provide sample input and output?

Comment: `/[a-z](?:-?[a-z])*/ig` matches your criteria and gets bonus points for not allowing `a--b` (two or more consecutive hyphens) ^_^

Comment: @MarkThomas, yes I am identifying the separators between words. I updated the question with how it looks like now and how it should. Thanks!

Comment: Can you also show your expected output from above example?

Comment: @anubhava Yes, it is the image below the first one. Or you can see it here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/3TaDJ.png

Comment: ok I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly.

**Instead of searching for the valid matches, what you want, I replaced all invalid matches.**

Have a look at this [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/kH7uG3)
It is matching all invalid matches according to your question, what I have understood.

**"Words are alphabetic strings that can contain dashes (-), they cannot start with dashes or end with dashes. Words cannot contain numerals or any other character besides single dashes and [a-zA-Z]."**

This is the Code

```
var str = 'word word-ed, [word-ing] 123-word w-word, word-. w0rd w14rd 124eword 1234word finished.'
str.replace(/(\b[\d]+-[a-zA-Z]+\b)|(\b[\d]+[a-zA-Z]+)|(\b[a-zA-Z]+[\d]+[a-zA-Z]+)|(\b[a-zA-Z]+-[.,]|([\[\],.]))/g, '').split(/\s+/)
```

**Output**

```
["word", "word-ed", "word-ing", "w-word", "finished"]
```

**Explanation:**

Search for Invalid matches

```
str.match(/(\b[\d]+-[a-zA-Z]+\b)|(\b[\d]+[a-zA-Z]+)|(\b[a-zA-Z]+[\d]+[a-zA-Z]+)|(\b[a-zA-Z]+-[.,]|([\[\],.]))/g)
//output
[",", "[", "]", "123-word", ",", "word-.", "w0rd", "w14rd", "124eword", "1234word", "."]
```

Replace with null

```
var temp = str.replace(/(\b[\d]+-[a-zA-Z]+\b)|(\b[\d]+[a-zA-Z]+)|(\b[a-zA-Z]+[\d]+[a-zA-Z]+)|(\b[a-zA-Z]+-[.,]|([\[\],.]))/g)
//output
"word word-ed word-ing  w-word      finished"
```

split the result with spaces

```
temp.split(/\s+/)
//output
["word", "word-ed", "word-ing", "w-word", "finished"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```regex
/(?<=[^\w-]|^)(?!-)([a-z-]+)(?<!-)(?=[^\w-]|$)/gi
```

Given an input as follows:

```
abc-def word A -notword xyz notword-
```

The above regex will match following words:

```
abc-def
word
A
xyz
```

[**Working demo**](http://regex101.com/r/xQ5bW5)

---

**UPDATE:** Based on edited question you can use this regex for splitting:

```
/([^\w-].*?)(?=(?<=[^\w-]|^)(?!-)[a-z-]+(?<!-)(?=[^\w-]|$))/gis
```

[**Working demo**](http://regex101.com/r/eM5fE0)

Comment: He wants to match the seperators, not the words.

Comment: It is not entirely clear, if you see example OP is trying to match `123-word` but trying to avoid `123-`. In any case getting separators is pretty easy using same regex approach if so desired by OP.

Comment: Can't the regex be shortened to just `(?<=\s|^)(?!-)([A-Za-z-]+)(?<!-)(?=\s|$)`? — [demo](http://regex101.com/r/wT8rD6)

Comment: Thanks @AmalMurali, yes it can definitely be reduced (see edited)

Comment: The update doesn't fare too well against his sample text. [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/gT0gJ8).

Comment: Actually as per OP `Words cannot contain numerals or any other character besides single dashes and [a-zA-Z]` so assuming this condition separator will be only when it is followed by `[a-zA-Z]`